# xml editing with exact formatting

Tags: c#, xml

I need to add atribute in some specific cases to large xml. But i must preserve exact formatting -> even if the is some inconsistency in it
e.g.

```
name="one"/>   
name = "one" />
```

or (length of indentation):

```
 <newtag .../>
  <newtag ... />
 <netag .../>
```

Can anyone have idea how to do this? Setting preservewhitespaces in XMLDocument cause that reading some XMLNode fails (beacuse there is whitespace instead of  < opening tag and the nullreferenceexception is thrown

Comment: Think you need to show larger portions of valid XML, and the code you're currently using, for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard off-the-shelf parser for XML that I am aware of that will preserve details like the whitespace around the "=" sign between attributes.

I don't think this requirement is achievable except by writing your own XML parser (or modifying an existing one).